# Read outlook mails through MS 365 graph client without login form

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have to read Outlook emails from an inbox in a Windows Console Application. I am trying to use MS Graph Client for the same. Problem is I don't want to login to generate access token. How should I go about generating access token without a login form ? I will appreciate any help.

I have tried the solution given in this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2016/02/12/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-and-office-365-api-in-a-service-or-in-a-windows-appuwp-without-a-graphical-interface/), but couldn't get it working as I didn't know redirectUrl and couldn't resolve some references for the given code.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the idea of an external process being able to read emails willy nilly.  Anyway your question is _too broad_ sadly.  [ask]

Comment: Your question isn't very specific. Is it meant to be without a user present (like an application access), or you want a way for the user to grant a one time permission for your application?

Comment: @Stephan It is meant to be without a user present.

Comment: entire organization or single specific user?

Comment: @Stephan I believe it is for entire organization. Actually, I am developing a Windows Console Application where one needs to read the emails of one mailbox. Presently, I am using Exchange Webservice, but I want to move to MS Graph API. I am new to Graph API. Is it required to be for single specific user ?

Answer (score 0):

**Single user -> Use device code flow**

If you want to access the mailbox of a single user: you can use the Device code flow [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-deviceprofile/).

This flow allows you to display a code to the user, they go to the device login page and authorize your application. You also get a refresh token so this access can be used for a log time.

**Any user in organization -> Use client credentials**

If you want to access any mailbox of the entire organisation you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55628757/639153) and replace the required permission by **Read mail in all mailboxes**.

Comment: @kany-priya can you let us know if this answer helped you? It's always nice to let people know if it helped.