# Microsoft Graph returns "The token contains no permissions, ..." when using app-only token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Using Postman, I am trying to retrieve the last emails received in my Outlook mailbox.

To achieve this, I have declared my app in the App Portal. Then, I can do a `GET` request to get a token from the endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantId]/oauth2/token
```

Next, I try to use the token I received to perform a request at

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages
```

The problem is that the API returns:

```
{
  "code": "NoPermissionsInAccessToken",
  "message": "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.",
}
```

In the permissions of my app, I have authorized every action related to reading emails. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. You're missing a lot of key details in your question: Which scopes exactly did you register for? How exactly did you call `/token`? Did you get "Admin Consent" for this app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was actually missing admin approval for the scopes (read.mail in my case). In a App-Only usage, you need to get approval from admin. To do so, admin must use this url:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=[your_client_id]&state=[random_string]&redirect_uri=http://localhost/`

Admin will be prompt to approve permissions.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like you forgot to "Grant permission" (it happens to the best of us :P).

Grant the permission for your tenant. The easiest way is through https://portal.azure.com -> Azure AD -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Settings -> Required permissions -> Button Grant Access.)

Related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55628757/639153)

It also helps to take the token, and paste in into https://jwt.ms which will show you all the data in the token (and should also show the claims about the granted permissions).

Answer (score 0):

The exception is the API to find meeting times or send mail, which applies to only **Office 365 mailboxes** (on Azure AD) and not to **Microsoft accounts**.

For simplicity of reference, the rest of this article uses Outlook.com to include these Microsoft account domains.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations